# How to refer to a variable with method scope from a different method called from method in which variable is declared?

Tags: java, methods, global-variables

Suppose if i have code like this -

```
    public class rectangle {
 int length, breadth; // Used some where else for different purpose/calculations
public int area(int length, int breadth)
{
int result = length*breadth;
resetvalues();
return result;

}
public void resetvalues()
 {
 length = "";
breadth = "";
}
```

So, in the above code, since i am calling resetvalues method from area, the length and breadth variables defined in area method are to referred/changed in resetvalues method rather than the ones declared in class level.

How to achieve this? How can i make resetvalues method refer to the variables declared in area method when it is called from that method?

Comment: Make it simple.. which variable in your code you want to refer and from where?

Comment: I wanted to refer length and breadth declared in area method from reset values method. Basically i wanted to change values of those two variables from different method which is called from the main method with variables declared in it.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in area() are local or method scoped. They cannot be accessed from outside the method. That is my understanding of variable scopes

You can reset the variable inside the area method directly and that would not affect the class variables:

```
public int area(int length, int breadth)
{
int result = length*breadth;
length = 0;
breadth = 0;
return result;

}
```

Here is a reference that gives clear descriptions:http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: assuming `length = "";
breadth = "";` must be `length = 0;
breadth = 0;`

Comment: Yes i can reset values of those in same method itself, but in my actual requirement i have many such variables, so i wanted to put them in a method and call from the actual main method. Also, the resetvalues method can be used else where.

Comment: The local copy of the variables will only exist for the duration of the method call. This has two points. 1. When the new call to area is made, it gets a fresh copy of the variables. 2. When the method area returns, the loacal copies do not exist anymore. Maybe am not following on what you are trying to get at.